# Java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: java, smtp, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I try to send an e-mail with the help of Pentaho, but something blocks my shipment. Can anyone help me? I get in the log:

```
  2019/04/02 14:35:29 - Mail - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Problem while sending message: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp..., port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

I have marked:
Use authentication? true
Use secure authentication? true
Secure connection type: TLS

Comment: somebody knows?

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with connecting to the mail server. You need to either double check your connection info, or you need to configure your mail server to work with Pentaho. For example, if you're trying to use Pentaho with Gmail, you need to set Gmail to "allow connections from less secure applications".